# Generic function to free 2d arrays with cleanup attribute in C

Tags: c, arrays, attributes, malloc, free

I've recently discovered `__attribute__((cleanup))` which is very handy. I have made a generic function to free any type of pointer and it works fine.

```
#define _autofree_ __attribute__ ((cleanup(free_pointer)))

...

void free_pointer(void *pointer)
{
    free(*(void **) pointer);
}
```

But it's not as easy when it comes to freeing 2d arrays.  As far as I know cleanup uses a pointer to the given pointer for stack restriction reasons, and it's a good thing because it doesn't use a *copy* of it at any point. Anyway, Dereferencing a `(void **)` cast to pass through "derefencing void *" errors works but then if I do

```
#define _autofree2d_ __attribute__ ((cleanup(free_pointer_array)))

...

void free_pointer_array(void *pointer_array)
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; (void **) pointer_array[i] ; ++i)
        free(*(void **) pointer_array[i]);
    free(*(void ***) pointer_array);
}
```

I end up dereferencing a void * because of the bracketed `[i]`. Also this just doesn't look right.

I'm also trying doing it in a less generic way using char pointers (as I'm currently working with a word array) and it compiles but gives we a segfault because of an invalid free.

```
void free_pointer_array(char ***array)
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; *array[i] ; ++i)
        free(*array[i]);
    free(**array);              // Tried using ***array and got
                                // "pointer from integer without a cast" error
}
```

Comment: If you allocate an actual array, instead of an array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays, you could free the array with a single call to `free()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Andrew Henle in the comments, my method of allocation was the problem. I was making a *look-up table* rather than an actual 2d array. Using the method described here : [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays), I can simply use my original `_autofree_` macro for arrays of any dimension.